# Proving that matrices $B$ produced by transposing two rows of $I$ satisfy $B=B^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

For example, I have a $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. If I exchange rows $2$ and $3$, then I get 
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0}.
$$
In this case it can be checked that $B=B^{-1}$.

I would like to show the following:

> If we exchange any two rows in an $n\times n$ identity matrix to get a new matrix $B$, then $B=B^{-1}$.

I tested other dimensions, such as $4\times 4$,  $5\times 5$ and $100\times 100$ on my Mathematica. But I don't know how to prove it?

Comment: @Casteels yes,you are right.May be I descibed my question not clear.

Comment: Note that _for the identity matrix_ switching two rows is the same as switching the corresponding two columns. That formulation is somewhat easier for this question if you are used to multiplying matrices from the left, since now the columns give the images of the standard basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching rows is equivalent to multiplication with a permutation matrix $P$, and because switching two times does "nothing" you have $P^2=I$ and therefore with $B=PI$ you get $B^2=BB=PIPI= PPI=II=I.$ And this shows $B^{-1}=B$.

Comment: Fantastic,I understand,thank you indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ denote the matrix formed by transposing the $i$th and $j$th rows of the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and let

It's easy to compute how $S$ acts in the standard basis $(e_a)$ of $\mathbb{F}^n$: We have $S e_i = e_j$, $S e_j = e_i$, and $S e_k = e_k$ for all $k \neq i, j$. In particular, for every basis element, $S^2 e_a S(S e_a) = e_a$, and so by linearity $S^2$ is the identity: $$S^2 = I.$$ In particular, $S$ is its own inverse.

More generally, matrices produced by permuting the rows of the $n \times n$ identity matrix are called *permutation matrices*, because they permute the standard basis. Any permutation of the standard basis can be encoded by a unique matrix of this type, so we can simply think of these matrices as the same thing as permutations on $n$ objects. A permutation matrix produced by transposing the $i$th and $j$th rows corresponds to the transposition permutation $(ij)$, and all transpositions are their own inverses.

Comment: I don't quite agree that _by construction_ one has $Se_i=e_j$ etc., since it was _rows_ that were swapped (that equation says that column $i$ of $S$ contains the same as column $j$ of the identity matrix). But see my comment that swapping rows is the same as swapping columns in this case.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for this, you're quite right. I wanted to omit that complication (which is only a complication inasmuch as row vectors and right multiplication seem less familiar to most people), which, like you say, we can in this case, because the matrix of any transposition is symmetric, but building this fact into "by construction" (which is what I first had in mind) is probably zealous at best and at worst misleading about the general case. Anyway, I'll change it now, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you switch rows $i$ and $j$ to get a matrix $B$. Let $e_{i}$ be the underlying basis, considered as row vectors. Now note that
$$
e_{k} B = e_{k}
$$
for $k \notin \{ i, j\}$,
while
$$
e_{i} B = e_{j},
\qquad
e_{j} B = e_{i}.
$$
Clearly you will have
$$
e_{k} B^{2} = e_{k},
$$
for all $k$, so $B^{2}$ is the identity.